# tensorflow tf.metrics

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have some questions about the tensorflow metrics (tf.metrics). There are some metrics available like accuracy, precision, false_positives etc.

According to the API precision etc. needs at least two arguments:

```
precision("ground truth values", "predicted values")
```

After "session.run" I have a result dictionary with some Tensor's, see the pictures below

[result dict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhEK.png)

[detection boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoYaW.png)

[groundtruth box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkkDf.png)

[detection scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGNZU.png)

How can I use this values to calculate accuracy, precision, false_positive etc. ?

I tried the following:

```
prec = tf.metrics.precision(result_dict['groundtruth_boxes'],  result_dict['detection_boxes'][0])
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 4 for 'precision/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [1,4].
```

Anyway my attempt makes no sense because for calculation of precision "true positives" and "false positives" are necessary.

Comment: Please don't link to screenshots of text... Paste the text directly in your question.

Comment: Nobody can help me???

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `tf.metrics` are mostly useful for computing running metrics over many batches. Because they need to keep state across `sess.run()` calls, they are not as simple as some folks assume. Here is a nice article explaining how they work: http://ronny.rest/blog/post_2017_09_11_tf_metrics/

For your question, arguments to `tf.metrics.precision` must (effectively) be boolean tensors. You can't directly feed bounding boxes. For example, the following would print `1.0`:

```
prediction = tf.constant([1., 1., 2., 2.])
label = tf.constant([1., 1., 3., 3.])
precision, update_op = tf.metrics.precision(label, prediction)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(update_op)
  print sess.run(precision)
```

because `2` and `3` are both non-zero.

You would need to compare the bounding boxes yourself (e.g. for each box do `tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(expected_box, predicted_box))`) so that for each box you will have a single `True/False` scalar. All these scalars put into a vector would become your `predictions` argument to `tf.metrics.precision`. The `labels` argument would be a Tensor of `True` the same size as `predictions`.